# Looking at htop, I see a process associated with a tab in firefox that isn't open. What gives?

Tags: security, firefox, htop

Earlier today I was ordering a yard sign for a local politician, via their website, through Firefox.

Just now I was doing some work in R, and checking `htop` to make sure I wasn't going to make my computer choke.  This caught my eye:

[image]

What is that highlighted line about?  The tab is the link that's long closed.  Is this an example of the website tracking me somehow?  Why would Firefox support this sort of behavior?

While I doubt that Elissa Silverman will do anything nefarious with data on my browsing habits, I'm perhaps a bit paranoid about what others might do.

Anyway, what is this and can I block it?  Should I block it?

Comment: Did you by chance close FF and then relaunch it? FF typically will reopen closed tabs.

Comment: Was Firefox possibly just launched with that website? e.g. Firefox was closed, you clicked (say) an email link or shortcut to open that site, Firefox launched, and the process now has that associated argument?

Comment: @Sparhawk yes I opened Firefox from a link that goes to that website. The leaves a "signature"?

Comment: @generic_user Sort of. I've created a longer answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, if you launch Firefox by clicking a link, the resulting process will be associated with that argument. In other words, Firefox was launched with the equivalent of typing something similar to the following on the command line.

```
$ firefox http://visited.website.com
```

This means that the process as reported by `htop` includes this full command. You can see similar full commands in your screenshot with `cinnamon` and `rsession`; both of these include arguments after the actual command.

Then, if Firefox is still open after you close the tab, the process is still running. There is no new process created, so `htop` still shows these arguments.

A analogous situation is if you open a text editor by specifying a particular document (e.g. `vim doc.txt`), then close the document in the editor. Again, `htop` will report the full command, even after the document has been closed.